# Search a 2 dimensional list for a string in another list

Tags: c#, list

I want to check if a value in one list is in a second list.  The second list is a 2 dimensional list defined in a class.

Here's some sample data.

```
tagNoMatchList[0] = "</Configuration>"
tagNoMatchList[1] = "<SWCheck>"
tagNoMatchList[2] = "</SWCheck>"

tagNoMatchList2[0].col = "A29"
tagNoMatchList2[0].tag = "</Configuration>"
tagNoMatchList2[1].col = "A52"
tagNoMatchList2[1].tag = "</SWCheck>"


public class tagNoMatchClass
{
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string col { get; set; }
}

var tagNoMatchList = new List<string>();
var tagNoMatchList2 = new List<tagNoMatchClass>();


tagNoMatchList2.Add(new tagNoMatchClass
{
    tag = formatTag,
    col = Globals.ConvertColumnNumberToName(Globals.HeaderColumns[Globals.COLUMN_FORMATTING_TAG]) + rowIdx.ToString(),
});

bool test = tagNoMatchList[formatTagError].Any(x => tagNoMatchList2.Any(y=>x.Equals(y.tag)));
```

In the code above, test always has a value of false.  It should be true when it tests tagNoMatchList[0] == tagNoMatchList2[0].tag and tagNoMatchList[2] == tagNoMatchList2[1].tag

I have tried various things and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you, jdweng. I must have my terminology wrong. I referred to tagNoMatchClass as a 2 dimensional List. It almost works, but not quite. The code below gives me exactly the opposite of what I want.

```
for (int formatTagError = 0; formatTagError < tagNoMatchList.Count; formatTagError++)
{
    if (tagNoMatchList2.Any(x => x.tag == tagNoMatchList[formatTagError])) 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I tried the following, but the if always evaluates to true.  There's something that I'm not understanding about the Any syntax.

```
for (int formatTagError = 0; formatTagError < tagNoMatchList.Count; formatTagError++)
{
    if (tagNoMatchList2.Any(x => x.tag != tagNoMatchList[formatTagError])) 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the *2 dimensional list*, i can only see `List<string>` and `List<tagNoMatchClass>`, may have you your terminology wrong, or i am not understanding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
    public class tagNoMatchClass
    {
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public string col { get; set; }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        List<string> tagNoMatchList = new List<string>();
        List<tagNoMatchClass> tagNoMatchList2;


        public Test()
        {
            tagNoMatchList2 = new List<tagNoMatchClass>();
            tagNoMatchList.Add("</Configuration>");
            tagNoMatchList.Add("<SWCheck>");
            tagNoMatchList.Add("</SWCheck>");

            tagNoMatchList2.Add(new tagNoMatchClass() {  col = "A29", tag = "</Configuration>"});
            tagNoMatchList2.Add(new tagNoMatchClass() {col = "A52", tag = "</SWCheck>"});

            bool test =   tagNoMatchList2.Any(x => x.tag == tagNoMatchList[0]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
for (int formatTagError = 0; formatTagError < tagNoMatchList.Count; formatTagError++)
{
    if (!tagNoMatchList2.Any(x => x.tag == tagNoMatchList[formatTagError]))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Thanks very much for getting me close enough to where I could figure out the rest.